# Can I have an independent clause follow by a dependent clause that is connected with a noun?

Tags: sentence-construction

> My art professor praised my work, saying I do "exceptional work and always go above and beyond."

Also, should I modify the quote to past tense?

Answer (score 1):

1. There's nothing wrong with the syntax here. I'm not sure a noun has anything to do with it; you have the independent clause "My art professor praised my work," and then you modify it with a dependent clause functioning as an adverb. Although the rest of the sentence has a quote and a compound verb, the structure is no different than: "The man walked through the grass, stepping lightly."
2. No, there's no need to change the tense, for a few reasons.

   1. The present tense can be used generically to describe general qualities: "They forgot my fries." "Yeah, they always do that."
   2. You presumably still continue to do exceptional work, and want to emphasize that.
   3. It's okay to alter a quote to fit the tense of the sentence. In academic writing, this should be made clear with brackets. Suppose someone in the 1700s predicted, "In 100 years we'll go to the moon." The prediction is in the present tense, but you can say "Benjamin Franklin predicted that "in 100 years we [would] go to the moon." In less formal writing, like any time that you're not also citing your source, you can make such small alterations without the brackets. So if your professor's letter was in the past tense ("She did exceptional work and always went above and beyond,") it's okay to alter the tense as long as you're not misrepresenting the professor's intent. And no, if the quote used the present tense, there's no need to alter it to the past tense just because it was written in the past.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think the problem is grammar or tense. I just think the structure is a bit awkward. I would simply split the quote:

> My art professor praised my work, saying I do "exceptional work" and "always go above and beyond."